# Set button below a button in a Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have to create a layout that have two buttons in that .Second button will be below the first one .See in this XML i have done that but i am not able to set the postion of the button below the button1.Please help me to get this .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ap"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TEST" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/st"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TEST" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TEST" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is second button here ?

Comment: i want to set put the second button below the android:id="@+id/button1"

Comment: add a LinearLayout with vertical orientation to wrap the two buttons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it with your button size:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ap"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TEST" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/st"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TEST" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TEST" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:text="Button" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

This way you can achieve the desired layout. Keep buttons in linear layout with vertical orientation.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ap"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TEST" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/st"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TEST" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TEST" />
    <LinearLayout

      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:text="Button" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:text="Button" />
       </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a LinearLayout with Vertical orientation inside the parent `linearLayout2` in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ap"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TEST" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/st"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TEST" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TEST" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
       <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adjust margins, weights and dimensions as you want.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ap"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TEST" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/st"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TEST" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TEST" />
        <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
              android:id="@+id/button1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="36dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:text="Button" />
            <Button
              android:id="@+id/button2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="36dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:text="Button" />
       </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put that right after the first button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Why using a LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout? One of them is superflu.

Answer (score 0):

Add the second button after `linearLayout2`.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the android:weightSum in the LinearLayout, and remove the layout_weight in all the views inside the LinearLayout.

Because you have set a weighSum of 3, the linearLayout will only show the first 3 items in it because they have a total weight of 3.

Answer (score 0):

With the first line it will be bellow your first button and with the seccond line, you say how big the gap between the two buttons is.

```
android:layout_below="@+id/button"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
```

Comment: Your answer pertains to `RelativeLayout`, not `LinearLayout`.